# Filtering specific comments on a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
#import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

req = urllib2.Request('https://www.sikayetvar.com/onedio', 
None,headers)
resp  = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = resp.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

complaints = soup.findAll('p', attrs = {'class' : 'complaint-summary'})


for complaint in complaints:
   if complaint.text.find("genç") is not -1:
      print complaint.text
```

I want to filter certain complaints that has a specific word in them on a website but I can't search for words with nonascii characters in them. I am using python 2.7 and beautifulsoup. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Can you provide a html tag which are you looking for?

Comment: <p class="complaint-summary">(.*?)<(/p) is the html tag

Comment: 1) may be better is to find in complaint.text?  2) try to print all complaint items .text's and check what are they irl

Comment: I get empty list of complaints, so I cannot test it. Could you please provide the full link?

Comment: 1. complaint.find will attempt to find a tag. You appear to be trying to use it to find text. I suggest you look at the methods of python's string type and use the appropriate one on complaint.text.

Comment: https://www.sikayetvar.com/onedio @leotrubach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube should change od statement to if your test is inside p tag

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

req = urllib2.Request('https://www.sikayetvar.com/onedio', 
None,headers)
resp  = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = resp.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

complaints = soup.findAll('p', attrs = {'class' : 'complaint-summary'})

for complaint in complaints:
    if b"genç".decode("utf-8") in complaint.text:
        print(complaint.text)
```

Comment: I get this error UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: how do I search for non-ascii chracters

Comment: I've edited the answer. It should return one complaint.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use python2. They will stop supporting it in the coming years.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

response = requests.get('https://www.sikayetvar.com/onedio',headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

complaints = soup.select('p.complaint-summary')
for complaint in complaints:
    if "genç" in complaint.text:
        print(complaint.text.strip())
```

Output will be

```
Ne yazık ki bir sosyal sitede ahlak dışı içerikli haberler durulmuyor. Çocuk ve gençler için sakıncalı olduğunu düşünüyorum. Fotoğraflarda saçma başlıkları görebilirsiniz. Başlıklardan anlaşılacağı üzere cinsel…
```